# Problem with SSL certificate after trouble shooting

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate

I enabled SLL with the simple SSL plugin on my website https:/www.untwine.eu

All 'sub-sites' and the Wordpress admin pannel are working fine (connection secure). However on my home page there seems to be a problem (attached picture).

[image: problem on my homepage]

I already tried to 'replace all' the http with https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to have images that goes agains http and not https
check this out

An image with an insecure url of "http://www.untwine.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/background-data-2.jpg" was loaded on line: 828 of https://www.untwine.eu/.
This URL will need to be updated to use a secure URL for your padlock to return.